# Getting error while intstalling xhtml2pdf>=0.0.6 in django 3.6

Tags: django

I am trying to install xhtml2pdf>=0.0.6 and reportlab>=2.7,<3  for rendering PDF file but while installation getting below error:Microsoft Visual c++ 14.0 required.I f any one knows about this error please let me know Thanks in advance

Comment: It means you have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0

Comment: @Bono: It doesn't. It means he should update his pip to allow using wheels or find a proper binary.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 3.6, [reportlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) did not release a binary wheel distribution for windows yet. Get one from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#reportlab) instead.

If you are using an older python, make sure you are using the latest pip by running:

```
pip install -U pip
```